# What does this regex means?

Tags: java, regex

I find this java regex, but don't understand what does it match?

`Pattern.compile("\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*(\\.\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*)*");`

What `javaJavaIdentifierStart` matches?

Comment: Please read the relevant documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix

Comment: @Matt Ball I searched I don't ask for everything but there is nothing about javaJavaIdentifierStart. A open even source file which comes from JDK 1.7 but from the code I understand nothing.

Comment: You can read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_character.htm) about these character classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}` means a character acceptable to be the first character of any valid java identifier.

`\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*\\.\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*` means `anyIdentifier.anyIdentifier` - two java identifiers, separated by dot (namespace name and class name, class name and static member name, object name and member name or etc.)

Full (corrected) regex means (maybe qualified) java identifier - simple "name" or a chain of "names", separated by dots. It is not neccessary for it to be a fully qualified name though.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is the equivilant of calling this method from the Character class of Java:

```
isJavaIdentifierStart

public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart(char ch)
Determines if the specified character is permissible as the first character in a Java identifier.
A character may start a Java identifier if and only if one of the following conditions is true:

isLetter(ch) returns true
getType(ch) returns LETTER_NUMBER
ch is a currency symbol (such as "$")
ch is a connecting punctuation character (such as "_").
Note: This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support all Unicode characters,     including supplementary characters, use the isJavaIdentifierStart(int) method.

Parameters:
ch - the character to be tested.
Returns:
true if the character may start a Java identifier; false otherwise.
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart%28char%29) (which is a bit more readable)

Answer (score 1):

This would match a fully qualified class name I believe.

Comment: So if ch = any correct java identifier then the pattern will look like:
   ch ch*(.ch ch*)*
For example:
com.example.parcers.xml